# Split a String - Vba based on symbols

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string like this `ABC$3$FG$H`and I want to split them into 4 different strings.

```
string1 - ABC, Number-3, string3-FG, String4 - H.
```

I am splitting the string with $ sign in the actual string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Split(String1,"$")
```

Quite enough. Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array containing a specified number of substrings.

If you want to look through the splitted string, this is a possible solution:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim str     As String
    Dim cnt     As Long

    str = "ABC$3$FG$H"
    For cnt = LBound(Split(str, "$")) To UBound(Split(str, "$"))
        Debug.Print Split(str, "$")(cnt)
    Next cnt

End Sub
```

[The MSDN documentation for Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function).